# Sql server LIKE get snippet from result

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-like, trim

Is it possible to get a snippet string  from results of a LIKE query?

I am not trying something fancy. All I want is the TRIM query string together with (i.e 50) chars from left and right of it.

For example, if LIKE returned

```
 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

for  query "fox", I want to get

```
 "brown fox jumps"
```

Update, this is what I have came up with. It seems to work

```
  declare @query nvarchar(100), @str nvarchar(100), @HowManyCharsToInclude int,     @startIndex int, @endIndex int, @cutfromLeft int, @cutFromRight int
set @HowManyCharsToInclude = 10
set @str='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
set @query = 'fox'
set @startIndex = (SELECT PATINDEX('%'+ @query+ '%', @str))
set @endIndex = (@startIndex + LEN(@query))
--set left, right cut
if(@startIndex>@HowManyCharsToInclude)
begin
set @cutfromLeft = @HowManyCharsToInclude
end
else
begin
set @cutfromLeft = @startIndex
end
--set right cut
if(LEN(@str) - @endIndex>@HowManyCharsToInclude)
begin
set @cutfromRight = @HowManyCharsToInclude
end
else
begin
set @cutfromRight = (LEN(@str) - @endIndex)
end

select  SUBSTRING(@str, @startIndex-@cutfromLeft, LEN(@query)+ @cutFromRight + @cutfromLeft)
```

Comment: As it works and if it comes up with response times your wanting, I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: Yes it's possible :D

Oh wait I should probably explain how...

Use built in string functions 
[MSFT String Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

in combination with finding the position in the result and knowing the length of the result..

so psudo code something like...

1 get start position of text being searched for in string if 0 do nothing else (17)

2 Next get the length of string being searched (3)

3 get length of entire result string (3x)

4 use substring to get characters to left substring(field,if (Results of 1 - 50<1 then 1 else results of 1-50) for 100+ length of string (3)

However all this added work will slow down your results, you're better off doing this type of manipulation outside the database layer.

A regular expression *may* work faster, I'd have to think about how to do it.

Comment: thanks, was working on something like that. Please see my update